# ActiveRecord OR Query in Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

For simple queries, OR queries are possible in ActiveRecord like this:

```
Model.where({:category => "XYZ", :item_id => some_ids})
=>
table = Model.arel_table
Model.where(table[:category].eq("XYZ").or(table[:item_id].in(some_ids)))
```

The result is not very compact and clear. What if you have more complex queries, 
is it possible and useful to write the following ActiveRecord query in Arel as well?

```
Model.where(["(item_id = ? AND item_type = 'ABC') OR 
              (item_id IN (?) AND item_type = 'XYZ')",id,more_ids]).
      order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: look at https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
first_part = arel_table[:item_id].eq(id).and(arel_table[:item_type].eq('ABC'))
second_part = arel_table[:item_id].in(more_ids).and(arel_table[item_type].eq('XYZ'))    

Model.where(first_part.or(second_part)).order(created_at: :desc)
```